# Should I follow up with a potential supervisor?

Tags: phd, application

I was talking to a potential supervisor on mail for quite some time, asking them different questions related to the PhD project. They didn't reply for quite sometime to the first email but after that they were very kind and generous when answering. The project ad was listed as available for students worldwide and they were kind enough to mention that part themselves, while stating that it will be the unis responsibility to which I agreed. I was invited to a video call to further discuss the project and what direction I would want to take it. They asked me about my thesis and about a prominent and common topic I was involved in (which they knew from my CV). I felt very comfortable talking to them, even though I had communication issues in the beginning we were laughing by the end of the discussion. They were even telling me about where their lab is located and what all to expect when coming to the uni.

They suggested me to apply for the position and email them the details so that they can have my profile on their desk, figuratively. I did apply, in fact twice, since one of my documents was wrong I had to withdraw one of my applications. I wrote a new email to them stating that one of my applications wasn't complete and I had to withdraw it, and I gave them the details of the new one.
They haven't responded yet, it has been couple of days after the deadline and I'm overthinking things to an extreme extent. Have I been rejected? Should I mail them again? Should I mail them a follow up query full of questions that I have already prepared?

Comment: What would you lose if you choose to follow up?

Comment: It's a couple of days after the deadline. The committee probably hasn't even met to review the applications yet (depending on the country, they may have Easter holidays around this time, for example). Just be patient. If you haven't heard after 3-4 *weeks*, I would consider writing a follow-up.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From the sound of your earlier interactions, I'd guess that the person isn't primarily responsible for your admission or rejection. A couple of days past the deadline is not enough time for decisions to reach you so you may have been rejected or not, but you need to wait for an official response.

But, yes, if someone is interested in your work then it is good to keep in contact for as long as it is fruitful. I suggest, however, that you don't flood them with questions. Ask one or two questions at a time. And the questions should be about the topic, not the admissions.

It is also good if you have something to add to the conversation, not just questions but results of your own explorations and any insights you might have.

Long term relationships, especially collaborations, are valued in academia, even if you wind up elsewhere.